# Enable Cors in Gulp/BrowserSync

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, gulp-browser-sync

I've created an Angular project with yeoman's boilerplate code ([generator-gulp-angular](https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular))

And now in my controller I'm trying to make a http request like this:

```
$http.get('http://food2fork.com/api/search?key='+key+'&page=1').then(function(response) {
    vm.all = response.data;
});
```

But I keep getting this error:

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://food2fork... (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing)

I did my research and found I needed to add this Access Control to my server,
using the middleware property, which I did, but I still keep getting an error here is my `server.js` file

```
var path = require('path');
var gulp = require('gulp');
var conf = require('./conf');
var cors = require('cors');

var browserSync = require('browser-sync');
var browserSyncSpa = require('browser-sync-spa');

var util = require('util');

var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

function browserSyncInit(baseDir, browser) {
  browser = browser === undefined ? 'default' : browser;

  var routes = null;
  if(baseDir === conf.paths.src || (util.isArray(baseDir) && baseDir.indexOf(conf.paths.src) !== -1)) {
    routes = {
      '/bower_components': 'bower_components'
    };
  }

  //here is where I added the middleware 
  var server = {
    baseDir: baseDir,
    middleware: function (req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        next();
      },
    routes: routes
  };      

  browserSync.instance = browserSync.init({
    startPath: '/',
    server: server,
    browser: browser
  });
}

browserSync.use(browserSyncSpa({
  selector: '[ng-app]'// Only needed for angular apps
}));

gulp.task('serve', ['watch'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([path.join(conf.paths.tmp, '/serve'), conf.paths.src]);
});

gulp.task('serve:dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e', ['inject'], function () {
  browserSyncInit([conf.paths.tmp + '/serve', conf.paths.src], []);
});

gulp.task('serve:e2e-dist', ['build'], function () {
  browserSyncInit(conf.paths.dist, []);
});
`
```

But still the error persists, any help?

Answer (score 2):

You are requiring http-proxy-middleware but not using it !
  If You want to resolve Cross Origin for all URL containing /api, first
you should forward your Angular requests to your BrowserSync Server

So

```
$http.get('http://food2fork.com/api/search?key='+key+'&page=1')
```

Should become

```
$http.get('/api/search?key='+key+'&page=1')
```

The BrowserSync will receive the call

In Browser relay the call to the real server in the back with

```
target :'http://food2fork.com/'
```

and add Cross Origin headers when the response comes back with

```
changeOrigin: true,
```

the full config becomes :

```
var proxyMiddleware = require('http-proxy-middleware');

const jsonPlaceholderProxy = proxyMiddleware('/api', {
  target: 'http://food2fork.com/api',
  changeOrigin: true,
  logLevel: 'debug'
});

module.exports = function() {
  return {
    server: {
      middleware: [jsonPlaceholderProxy],
      baseDir:  baseDir
    }
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add additional information on the server side which headers and methods are allowed. For example:

```
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
```

or

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
```

This will tell the server to accept the headers send by the client (e.g. Origin) as well as the HTTP methods which you plan to support (e.g. GET).

For further informations on CORS see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Comment: still the same error,
is this the only place I have to do that, maybe its somewhere else...


`var server = {
    baseDir: baseDir,
    middleware: function (req, res, next) {
        res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
      res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, DELETE, PUT");
        next();
      },
    routes: routes
  };  `

Comment: You should still set  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'); as well

Comment: Could you please post the preflight OPTIONS request?

Comment: I would if I knew what is that :/

Comment: Look into your browsers developer console - when you send the request in the network tab you should see one request with method "OPTION" - and you should definitely read about CORS in the link i posted in the answer ;)

Comment: OK, I will read, the thing is I don't see any OPTION method only ones are GET and POST (Mozilla/Network tab)